# Application Context cannot cast to Activity Context

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mobile-application

Here's the function:

```
public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(
            final Context context) {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        (Activity) context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat
                            .requestPermissions(
                                    (Activity) context,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here's the error, that I am getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: MyApp.App, PID: 10585
    java.lang.ClassCastException: MyApp.App cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
        at MyApp.utility.FileUpload.GenericFileUploader.checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(GenericFileUploader.java:209)
```

The function that's not being cast to Activity is required to check and/or grant permission for file access. Some insights are much appreciated (and required).

Comment: You already pass your context as argument, why you cast it inside your function. Try to remove your cast

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim: `requestPermissions()` needs an `Activity` and not just any old context.

Comment: @MokhtarAbdelhalim , I actually tried that, but `ActivityCompat` demands further `Activity`. So, even though there is a context in the parameter, it is required in the body too. @JoachimSauer , what may work around ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear:
cast (Activity) context throw an exception because context don't represents an Activity.
This exception will be more clear if instead of receive Context as param, you'll receive an Activity param.
In this case, most probably the APP will not compile.

You have to undertand why received context isn't an Activity, and , if this function isn't fundamental for your project, you can put all in a try-catch and resolve APP stopping.

Comment: I got your point, but, the function is needed. So, could you tell me some other workaround?

Comment: you can put input params as Activity intead of Context and you can understand if something wwong if compiler fails.
Unfortunately i don't think there are other ways: you have to understand why context isn't an activity.
Check where function is called and check caller context.
Try to understand where is the call that bring APP fails, and if you want, post  code of class, and i'll check it.

Comment: Many other classes inherits this one and the type they require is `Context`, so as I edited the `Context` to `Activity` and compile the code, I get more errors, tracing each one of them is not good idea, I guess.

Comment: but if compiler throws errors, you have to resolve them! this errors indicates that input params is not valid, and without catch errors the APP will crash.
My suggest is to insert a try catch in the method (always helpfull) and then resolve an errore a time.